# re not getting all matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I'm having some issues with the text extraction from the following string:

```
'Amount\n2144-PL\n1XL 2XL 3XL\n2144-\nPL Navy Blue 2 2 2 6 $11.50 $69.00\nETK-2097K-PL PLUS-TOP - 
 BACK BUTTON TUNICS 95% RAYON 5% SPANDEX MADE IN USA\n1XL 2XL 3XL\nBlack 2 2 2 6 $12.00 $72.00\nTeal 
 2 2 2 6 $12.00 $72.00\nETK-2197-SW-\n1XL 2XL 3XL\nPL ETK-\n2197- H.Grey/Burgu… 2 2 2 6 $14.00 
 $84.00\nOff-White/Black 1 1 1 3 $14.00 $42.00\nETK-2143 Tops - 95% RAYON 5% SPANDEX MADE IN USA\nS M 
 L\nHeather Grey 2 2 2 6 $10.50 $63.00\nRoyal Blue 2 2 2 6 $10.50 $63.00\nRuby Red 2 2 2 6 $10.50 
 $63.00\nETK2186-GD- Tops-Stripe Solid-95% Rayon 5% Spandex Made in USA\nPL\n1XL 2XL 
 3XL\nBurgundy/Bur… 2 2 2 6 $11.00 $66.00\nIvory/Black 2 2 2 6 $11.00 $66.00\n2139 - WP-PL PLUS TOP 
 -95% RAYON 5% SPANDEX MADE IN USA\n1XL 2XL 3XL\nAs Shown 2 2 2 6 $9.50 $57.00\nETK-2228\nS M L\nETK- 
 \n2228 Off-White/Black 2 2 2 6 $9.50 $57.00\nETK-2149-PL\n1XL 2XL 3XL\nETK-\n2149- Taupe 2 2 2 6 
 $11.50 $69.00\nBACK\nORDERED\nWhite 2 2 2 6 $11.50 $69.00\nSub'
```

I'm looking for the `\nOff-White/Black 1 1 1 3 $14.00 $42.00\n` pattern to get all the items in the string but for some reason I'm not getting  all the matches with the following regex:

```
item_quantity_price = re.compile(r"\n[A-Za-z0-9-_./\s]*\d[\s]\d[\s]\d[\s]\d[\s][$]\d\d\d?.\d{2}[\s] 
[$]\d\d\d?.\d{2}\n")
```

Any information will be appreciated.

Best regards.

EDIT:
Using : `\n[A-Za-z0-9-_./\s]*(?:\s\d+){4}\s\$\d+.\d+\s\$\d+.\d+\n`

results:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCNOx.png)

Comment: Does the string really contain literal `\n` or are those newlines that are shown with escape sequences?

Comment: Those are new lines

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put `\s` inside `[]`.

Comment: `\d[\s]\d[\s]\d[\s]\d[\s]` can be simplified to `(?:\d\s){4}`

Comment: `re.findall(r"\nOff-White\/Black(?:\s\d+){4}\s\$\d+.\d+\s\$\d+.\d+\n", s)` will it work?

Comment: Please post the actual code, don't add line breaks in the middle of strings.

Comment: Use `^` and `$` along with the `re.MULTILINE` flag to match beginning and end of line, rather than `\n` in the regexp.

Comment: Thankk you for  your comment, using this part  (?:\s\d+){4}\s\$\d+.\d+\s\$\d+.\d+\n, i was able to get better results, also will update the post, now I'm able to get more matches, but still not all of them

Comment: You need to escape the `.` characters to match them literally.

Comment: Thank you so much, is already working, i was able to get all the matches with:  item_quantity_price = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z0-9-_./\s]*(?:\s\d+){4}\s\$\d+.\d+\s\$\d+.\d+$", re.MULTILINE)

Comment: You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Some of your products have two spaces between the prices. You should use `\s+` to match them.

Comment: And some of the product descriptions have `%` and `…` characters. You should add them to `[A-Za-z0-9-_./\s]` if you want to match those products.

Comment: Happy my answer worked for you. Please also kindly upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
item_quantity_price = re.compile(r'^[\w\s./-]*(?:\s\d+){4}(?:\s\$\d+\.\d+){2}$', re.M | re.A)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/eOzZaV/1). With `re.A` `\w` becomes equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and you can shorten the expression.

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w\s./-]*               any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " "), '.', '/', '-' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (4 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){4}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        the end of the line
```